# response error google maps api volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley, google-maps-api-2

i created an application that retrieved data from mysql databse. the problem is that the map does not show any marker .
i am using volley library

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    String uri = "localhost/get_all_products.php";
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(
            uri,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                LatLng location;
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int count = response.length();
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lat"));
                            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(jo.getString("lng"));

                            location = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                            options.position(location);
                            options.title(jo.getString("product"));
                            options.snippet(jo.getString("product"));
                            mMap.addMarker(options);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location);
                    mMap.moveCamera(cu);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onErrorResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
    Object TAG_REQUEST_QUEUE = new Object();
    request.setTag(TAG_REQUEST_QUEUE);
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
    mRequestQueue.start();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

the map is rteurn without any markers and the application does not crash.

the php files are correct so there is no need to put the code here

thank you :)

--------EDIT

the volley error  i get is

```
org.json.JSONException: value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: retrieving the data from database and showing markers are two different things, check the response first and the error you are getting

Comment: the error is org.json.JSONException: value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: it means you are not getting valid JSON data, try to fix your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not in the java or php files. 
the host "byethost14.com"  is not giving a valid json format for security purposes i guess. 
i changed the url to 10.0.2.2 and uploaded my files in xamppserver  and it's working
-------advice------
do not use  byethost if you want to output json